# Azure Pipelines build Vue CLI app failed but succeeds locally

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, eslint, vue-cli-3

I have a CI pipeline in Azure Devops which has a stage to build my ASP.NET Core app which includes VueJS.

Running the command in my client app:

```
npm run build
```

Resulted in errors like:

[image]

When running the command locally was also given me the same errors so I solved it by changing the following files:

Installed the following package:

```
"babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
```

Updated my babel config:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app'
  ],
  env:{
     production: {
         plugins: ["transform-remove-console"]
     }
  } 
}
```

Updated my eslint config:

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "vue/no-unused-vars": "off"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
```

After running the command again locally the errors where gone. When I pushed the changes to my Devops and rerunning the build process CI with these new changes, the errors are still there.

Any ideas?

**Update**

[image]

**Update 2**

When I seperated my eslint config to a `.eslintrc.js` file and setup following rules:

```
"rules": {
  "no-unused-vars": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
  "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
  "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off"
}
```

I get warnings instead of errors and the build process continues. When I look in the artifact, the destination folder contains the script files. Also when I search for `console.log` I don't get any results... ?

So the errors are thrown before babel is running his plugin?

Comment: Are you running exactly `npm run build` in your Azure build or are there extra parameters that adjust the strength of the linting?

Comment: View update in my question with screenshot of the task in the pipeline console

Comment: Do you try using the private agent to see if the error still exists?

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT you mean setting up a hosted server with an azure agent to run the build?

Comment: @Mivaweb I mean setting up a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops#install) to run the build.